Unexpected Findings: Laptop Memory Details Indicate DIMM Slots – Is This Correct?
I'm planning to upgrade the RAM in my laptop and wanted to ensure I get the right memory type. I've read that laptops typically use SODIMM memory, while desktops use DIMM memory.
However, when I used the command wmic MemoryChip get DeviceLocator to check the memory details on my laptop, the output showed:
DeviceLocator
DIMM A

Is this a mistake or is there a reason my laptop might be using DIMM slots despite being a laptop?

details:

model: dell inspiron 3793
Operating system: Windows


These are the results:
DIMM A         12
The link seems to answer my question, but there is also a theoretical question about the wmic information error

magnificent! If this is understandable, do you have a link with a reference for this?

now i understand Should I answer my own question?

The answer is not twice.
No, this is not a mistake, but a correct answer.
And no, the laptop does not support desktop DDIM
Since a SODIMM is technically a type of DIMM, it's displayed as such with the wmic command.
To get the RAM memory and its specific type, run the following command:
wmic memorychip get devicelocator, formfactor

This command returns DIMM A 12, representing a type 12 RAM DIMM, which is actually a SODIMM.
Source: Microsoft - Win32_PhysicalMemory class
